# Is it "Chinese simplified", or "simplified Chinese"?

Tags: word-choice, word-order

What is the correct way to call one of the scripts used for Chinese? Chinese simplified, or simplified Chinese?

Comment: If anything it should be *Chinese, simplified*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anecdotally, all the Chinese learners that I know refer to it as "Chinese simplified" or just "simplified" or "traditional".

According to [google](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=%22Chinese+simplified%22&word2=%22simplified+Chinese%22), it's the most common phrase.

Comment: Interestingly, [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chinese+simplified%2Csimplified+chinese&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cchinese%20simplified%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BChinese%20simplified%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BChinese%20Simplified%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Csimplified%20chinese%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsimplified%20Chinese%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSimplified%20Chinese%3B%2Cc0) from Google Books lists the opposite, with "simplified Chinese" dramatically more common.

Answer (score 10):

"Simplified Chinese" is the normal way to describe this. But as far as I know, it refers to the system of writing, not the language. Hence it is ["Simplified Chinese characters"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_Chinese_character) (link to Wikipedia article).

Comment: That's correct; it would be like to say that Cyrillic is a language. Thank you for the note; I fixed the question.

Comment: The answer is the same.

Comment: +1 Your are right they simplified i.g. bird from 鳥 to 鸟.

Comment: @stacker: still doesn't look like a bird to me..

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Hmm. I'm actually not sure that you are right; while alphabetical writing systems certainly do not qualify as languages, it's a bit fuzzier with ideograph-based writing systems: each ideograph actually has its own meaning. In fact, "Chinese" is arguably not the name of a spoken language (though the Party may disagree!): rather, there are such languages as Mandarin, "Wu", and "Yue" (to pick the first three listed in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_language)), all of which share a common written language (which *is* Chinese).

Comment: @kiamlaluno: However, Simplified Chinese is (thankfully) not actually a different language from [traditional] Chinese: it is "just" a different way of writing the same symbols. (Assuming we treat each ideograph as an atomic unit, that is: things are a bit different if we consider the treatment of their components.)

Answer (score 2):

I've studied Mandarin for years and all references I've come across, from course titles to textbooks have been to *simplified Chinese*.  Incidentally, I wish that I'd had the option to study traditional Chinese at a local university.